# SQL prepare data to display charts

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to build chart of registered users (per day)

I will be use google charts, so i should have data to use

I wrote a SQL query which count registered users by day

```
SELECT DATE(created_at), COUNT(DISTINCT id) amount 
FROM users 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

this returns me a hash with data and users count

```
{"date"=>"2013-09-24", "amount"=>"100"} 
{"date"=>"2013-09-26", "amount"=>"1"} 
{"date"=>"2013-10-01", "amount"=>"2"}
```

Problem:

I want to display 0 registrations for days when no any new users, like

```
{"date"=>"2013-09-25", "amount"=>"0"}
```

(I'm using pg database, also i use this query in rails app, so you could give me an advice using ActiveRecord)

---

```
                           **UPDATE**
```

for my rails application, i figured out this problem in such way

```
#controller
  def charts
    users = User.select([:id, :created_at])
    @data = users.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today - 1.month)
    @inf = [] 
    @date = [] 
    month = Date.today - 1.month
    month.upto(Date.today).each do |date| 
      @date << date.strftime('%d/%m')   
      @inf << @data.select{|u| u.created_at.to_date == date }.size
    end 
  end
```

in `@inf` and `@date` arrays i have count of register users and date.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a source of all the dates that you wish to consider.

e.g from first entry to now

```
WITH cte_days 
AS 
( 
    SELECT MIN(DATE(created_at)) AS [Day] FROM USERS -- First registered User
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [Day]) 
    FROM cte_days
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [Day]) < GETDATE() -- Stop at today
)
SELECT [Day], COUNT(DISTINCT id) amount 
FROM cte_days LEFT JOIN users ON [Day] = DATE(created_at)
GROUP BY [Day]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the database you are using but as no one has answered this yet this is how I would go about it in MSSQL

```
  DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME
  DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME
  SET @MinDate = '01 Jan 2013'
  SET @MaxDate = '31 Jul 2013'

  ;with d(date) as (
  select @MinDate
  union all
  select date+1
  from d
  where date < @MaxDate
  )
  select d.date created_at, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) amount
   from d
   left join users u
        on u.created_at = d.date
     GROUP BY d.date
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

You only need `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` for a date range > 100 days